# HashMap Performance when overriding hashcode method

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

In a `HashMap`, if I put custom objects as a key.

What would happen if I override 
`hashCode()` method and implement it to pass value as '`1`'; would there be any performance hit ?

if I change `hashCode()` method to return random value using `Math.random()` function
what would happen to performance ?

Comment: Try it and see. However, this can only be out of curiousity because `hashCode` is not arbitrary.

Comment: If you changed the `hashCode()` method to return a random value, performance might do many things -- but your program would completely crash, because it wouldn't get correct results anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Adding Math.random() doesn't affect much performance hit but it is a bad idea to construct hashcode values through random() function. Instead you can use some of the good hashing function to minimize the collision and which are much faster also.
For reference you can check out some of the links
http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to the asymptotic time complexity then:

since `HashMap` uses `hashCode` to calculate which bucket to use in the hashtable if you return `1` from `hashCode` you effectively make your `HashMap`'s performance be like an (unsorted) `LinkedList`'s performance.

Returning random values will simply blow your `HashMap` up since `equal` objects will no longer have equal `hashCode`s.

Excerpt from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_data_structure):

```
+----------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+
|                      |  Insert  |   Delete   |  Search  | Space Usage  |
+----------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+
| Unsorted linked list | O(1)*    | O(1)*      | O(n)     | O(n)         |
| Hash table           | O(1)     | O(1)       | O(1)     | O(n)         |
+----------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+
```

So to sum it up you lose:

- Time complexity when searching your `HashMap` (from `O(1)` to `O(n)`)
- lookup in your `HashMap` (it won't work anymore)

Comment: What is the purpose of the table you have inserted here?

Comment: Ok I cut out the non-relevant parts.

Answer (score 2):

Always returning `1` in `hashCode()` will degrade the performance of `HashMap`. Every object defaults to the same bucket, and the hash tables become linked lists. According to [Effective Java, item 9](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf), you get quadratic time instead of linear.

Returning a random value will violate the provision that equal objects have equal hashCodes, you won't be able to retrieve the stored objects.

Comment: You slighty misinterpreted that sentence from Effective Java. On average, a hash access is *O(1)*, whereas a linked list (or a degenerate hash table) has *O(n)* access time. So if you have an algorithm that does a hash access *n* times this has *O(n)* average complexity (because *O(n) = O(n) · O(1)*) but *O(n²)* worst case complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you always returned `1` (or any other constant value for all objects to be inserted), then the `HashMap` would internally degrade to be a "linked list". This means that insertion, deletion and querying would no longer have a complexity of O(1), but of O(n), and impose a potentially severe performance penalty.

If you returned random values, then the `HashMap` would simply become inconsistent. It could happen that the "same" key appeared twice (although according to the specification, each key may only appear once). It may also happen that you will not find the value for a certain key, although you previously inserted it (with a different hashCode).

The exact behavior will then also depend on the implementation of the `equals` method, but these are the main effects that such an implementation would have.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a fixed value in hashcode() will definitely make your hashtable run slower. All values will be assigned to the same bin, therefore lookup operations will take linear time (instead of the average constant time with a decent hash function).

Returning a random value will break the hashmap contract completely. Values will be assigned to random bins and looked up in random bins, so nothing guarantees you'll find values stored previously.