# How will Hashmap key behave if hash code is overridden such that it returns only a constant number?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I have a small question about Java `Hashmap`. If I override the `hashCode` method such that:

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
  return 9;
}
```

This will cause all the `HashMap` keys to have the same index. Will they be placed in a linked list structure in the map or will the map only contain the last key which has replaced all the other keys?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HashMap Performance when overriding hashcode method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939639/hashmap-performance-when-overriding-hashcode-method)

Comment: That method does not override `hashCode()` in `Object` because the name is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will be placed in a linked list structure in the map, assuming you didn't override the `equals` method to always return true. Different keys may have the same hashCode, but if all the keys have the same hashCode, your HashMap would become a linked list, which defeats the purpose of using this structure in the first place.

You can see it for yourself in a `HashMap` implementation :

```
/**
 * Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map.
 * If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old
 * value is replaced.
 *
 * @param key key with which the specified value is to be associated
 * @param value value to be associated with the specified key
 * @return the previous value associated with <tt>key</tt>, or
 *         <tt>null</tt> if there was no mapping for <tt>key</tt>.
 *         (A <tt>null</tt> return can also indicate that the map
 *         previously associated <tt>null</tt> with <tt>key</tt>.)
 */
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode()); // hash would always be the same if hashCode is constant
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length); // i would always be the same if hashCode is constant
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) { // the key is searched using the
                                                                       // equals method
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Excellent , that's what I wanted to know . This clears it up for me. Thanks .

Comment: This is no longer true in Java 8, where if too many elements go into the same bucket, it will switch to using a red-black tree.

Answer (score 1):

Hashcode values are used to reduce the search time of an object .
The hashcode value does not necessarily be unique for distinct objects. The hashCode() method may in fact, be overridden in such a way that it returns a constant integer for all objects (this would however defeat the purpose of hashCode() method). However, the default implementation of class Object does return a unique integer for every object, as it maps the internal address of the object to an integer and returns the same. But this is not a requirement

Answer (score 0):

Whether it appears as a linked list or not is debatable as it does not state in the documentation. However, it will certainly keep all items with unique keys (i.e. keys that return `true` to the `equals` method).

```
class Nine {

    final String value;

    public Nine(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object it) {
        return it instanceof Nine && ((Nine) it).value.equals(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}

class AlwaysNine extends Nine {

    public AlwaysNine(String value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object it) {
        return it instanceof Nine;
    }
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    Map<Nine, String> testMap = new HashMap<Nine, String>();
    testMap.put(new Nine("Nine"), "Nine");
    testMap.put(new Nine("nine"), "nine");
    testMap.put(new AlwaysNine("nIne"), "nIne");
    System.out.println(testMap);
}
```

prints

```
{Nine=nIne, nine=nine}
```

which proves that only overriding `equals` will force keys to seem to be the same ... as expected because `hashCode` is only used to pick the bucket in which to place the object.

Comment: You didn't override `hashCode()`.

Comment: @DavidConrad - I just noticed! Fixing it now. Thanks.

Comment: If you annotate with `@Override`, the compiler will warn you.